# C# retrieve data from database matching user start time

Tags: c#, sqlite, ado.net

I am tasked to retrieve data from a database and the user can select the starting time.  For example, if the user select from 13:00 and there is not result at that time, the reading should start a minute before (12:59), if still nothing 2 minutes before (12:58) until a result is found.  This is what I have been trying so far without success:

```
string str1 = dtFrom.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
string str2 = dtTo.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");

bool b = true;
while (b)
{
    string SQLCommand = "Select * From tbl Where Time Between @from AND @to AND Id = @id ";
    using (SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString))
    {
        con.Open();
        SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(SQLCommand, con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@from", str1);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@to", str2);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);

        using (SQLiteDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                DateTime time = DateTime.Parse(reader[0].ToString());
                double value = double.Parse(reader[1].ToString());
                if (time.Minute < dtFrom.Minute)
                {
                     // Add values..   
                     b = false;        
                }
                else
                {
                    dtFrom = dtFrom.AddMinutes(-1);
                    str1 = dtFrom.ToString();
                    b = true;
                    break;
               }
            }
        }
    }
}            
return list;
```

Comment: Can't you just order the records by descending time and take the first?

Comment: I am performing interpolation and if there is not such record the reading should start earlier.

Comment: I would have to agree with paul.  Why wouldn't you just change your query to be `"Select top 1 * From tbl Where Time <= @to AND Id = @id "`.  It makes no sense to me why you would limit the starting point of your search...

Comment: The user selects a range from and to, this is the requirement.  I really wish would smt more easier.

Comment: @doro If the user is selecting the filters, then why are you looping and manipulating them?  Also, I suspect that there may be a logic issue with `if (time.Minute < dtFrom.Minute)`.  What happens if `dtFrom` is 12:00 and `time` is 11:59?  Is the comparison correct?

Comment: Do you know something are linear Interpolation?

Answer (score 0):

To get the *latest* entry at or before a time, use ORDER BY and LIMIT, or simply MAX():

```sql
SELECT MAX(Time)
FROM tbl
WHERE Time <= @from
```

You can then use this value as the lower limit:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM tbl
WHERE Time BETWEEN (SELECT MAX(Time)
                    FROM tbl
                    WHERE Time <= @from)
               AND @to
  AND Id = @id
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you right:

Dataset:

```
ID:01 From:01/10/2014 13:00 To:02/10/2014 13:00
ID:02 From:01/10/2014 14:00 To:02/10/2014 14:00
ID:03 From:01/10/2014 15:00 To:02/10/2014 15:00
ID:04 From:01/10/2014 16:00 To:02/10/2014 16:00
ID:05 From:01/10/2014 17:00 To:02/10/2014 17:00
ID:06 From:01/10/2014 18:00 To:02/10/2014 18:00
```

User Requests: From:01/10/2014 14:01.

Like the others have suggested, what would be wrong with

```
select top 1 * from tbl, where from <= @From
```

For @From = 14:01, this would return ID: 02.

Going further: Is the user able to request a to/end time? If so, how would that work?

If this is not suitable, maybe you could comment what a user would search for, based on the dataset above, and what you would expect as a result.

Regards.

Comment: I am performing Interpolation and the data come from a database, which contains data even one year before from user start time point.